# Записать вводимый текст c консоли в файл в виде скрипта bash

Tags: linux, bash

Стоит задача что бы весь вводимый текст с консоли в полях перенаправить его в файл.
Подсказки вводимой команды делаю через echo

```
#!/bin/bash/

echo "Enter yuor group:"

read group
```

и далее введенный текст нужно перенаправить в файл `~/test_directory`

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

непонятно в чём у вас загвоздка

здесь подойдёт стандартное перенаправление потока с вывода переменной в файл:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter yuor group:"

read group
echo "$group" > ~/test_directory
```